# how to URL encode in EUC(CP51932) with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, urlencode, x-www-form-urlencoded

When I use Request with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, I want to encode the body.

For example, I want to encode the string, "その他".

I used the function, `encodeURIComponent()`, which result is "%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%96".

But I want that the result of encoding is "%a4%bd%a4%ce%c2%be".

how to get the encoded result with nodejs?

or which model do I use?

Conclusion: 'その他' -> '%a4%bd%a4%ce%c2%be' (endcoded)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `encoding-japanese` package available on NPM.

```
npm install encoding-japanese
```

The following code should produce your desired output:

```
const encoding = require('encoding-japanese')

const buf = Buffer.from('その他')
const convertedText = encoding.convert(buf, 'EUCJP', 'UTF8')
const result = encoding.urlEncode(convertedText)

console.log(result) // %A4%BD%A4%CE%C2%BE
```